# django error loading of image with non ascii character

Tags: django

I am getting following error when trying to visit website with image which name contains non ascii character:
IOError at /obiekty/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/darnok/fitspace/media/obiekty/orlik_SP_4_Zamo\u015b\u0107.png'

Funny thing is that on my localhost when using django development server everything worked fine.
I tried both development server on vps as well as gunicorn, it is the same in both cases. I dont know if that is related but I use app image-kit for handling images resizes. I even tried to clear the cache browser, nothing changes.

Issue related settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
```

Model Field:

```
zdjecie = models.ImageField('zdjęcie', upload_to='obiekty')
zdjecie_thumb = ImageSpecField(source='zdjecie', processors=[ResizeToFill(133, 100)], format='JPEG', options={'quality': 100})
```

Template line causing issue:

```
<a href="{{x.get_absolute_url}}"><img alt="zdjecie {{x.nazwa}}" src="{{x.zdjecie_thumb.url}}"></a>
```

Comment: Hmm `zdjecie = models.ImageField('zdjęcie', upload_to='obiekty')` can you please check if this works `zdjecie = models.ImageField('zdjecie', upload_to='obiekty')`

Comment: Siema:) I would do that but simply resaving troublesome image in admin helped my issue as only one image file name of my 40 objects contained no ascii character. Moreover, I think it must have sth to do with the file itself, not directory, because the rest of images worked. It looks like copying 1 image to my website from windows 7 to debian vps using winSCP application could have corrupt the file due to its name?